# DataStax Enterprise server won't start: dse dead but pid file exists

Tags: cassandra

When I launch it with `sudo /etc/init.d/dse start` it seems to work. It returns:

```
Starting DSE daemon dse
DSE daemon starting with Hadoop and Solr disabled (edit /etc/default/dse to enable)
```

But when I try to connect to the tutorial "Test Cluster" (so localhost) with `opscenter` (on a distant machine but with port 8888 shared), I got this error:

```
Error creating cluster: Unable to connect to cluster
```

And if I check the health of dse with `sudo /etc/init.d/dse status`: I got:

```
dse dead but pid file exists
```

Original Post: http://www.datastax.com/support-forums/topic/dse-dead-but-pid-file-exists#post-14982

Comment: Something useful in your logs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The console or /var/log/cassandra/output.log will likely contain something like this (where nodename1 is whatever you named your node):

Error: Exception thrown by the agent : java.net.MalformedURLException: Local host name unknown: java.net.UnknownHostException: nodename1: nodename1

Same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7496640/problem-on-starting-cassandra, basically you need to make sure that the hostname you are using can be resolved (by putting it into /etc/hosts).